# Material Problem: nougat filling of a chocolate bar

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm barely new to Blender and I'm trying to create this chocolate bar. I have serious problems with the inside material. I've tried various shaders but nothing is close enough. Are there any suggestions?
Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: First off, this is looking great so far! One of the issues I am seeing is the lighting is very sharp, it looks like the reference has a lot of light from the bottom filling in those ugly shadows for example.

Comment: Just as a more general tip: the colors of the node connectors should (almost) always match. You are plugging color into a vector socket. That probably messes up your SSS. Start with the Principaled BSDF alone. Simply increase the SSS from the default node values and go from there.